# Same app, same test user, two different devices with different SKPaymentQueue contents. What could cause this?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have two iPhones I use for testing my app.

**On Device A:**

```
NSLog(@"Unfinished Transactions: [%i]", [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue].transactions count]);
```

Which outputs: "Unfinished Transactions: [0]"

When when I do a:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]
```

the function

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

gets called with 17 items in the transactions array, each flagged as RESTORED. So, I loop over the set and call `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction]` on each.

After processing each item, `(void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue` is called, and `[[queue transactions] count]` is equal to 4, not 17, which is something of a surprise.

If I re-run `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]` on this device, I repeatedly get the same result - despite having told each transaction I want it removed from the queue, updatedTransactions gets called with 17 items to process.

**On device B,**

```
$NSLog(@"Unfinished Transactions: [%i]", [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue].transactions count]);
```

Still outputs "Unfinished Transactions: [0]"

When I run

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]
```

, the function

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

NEVER gets called. Eventually

```
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
```

is called, with

```
[[queue transactions] count]
```

equal to 0.

What could be causing this? It's almost like the payment queue is linked to the device ID, not the  Test Account Apple ID. Also, please forgive the terrible formatting of this question, I'm still getting used to StackOverflow. :)

Comment: I've tried it again on another device (an iPad) with the same test account. I get 0 unfinished transactions, 31 transactions restored, and 31 transactions in the queue on `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished`. This is maddeningly inconsistent.

Comment: Nope. We eventually decided that in-app purchases for a subscription was just not going to work well enough

Comment: for my experience. my problem having only in debug version. works fine after released to app store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a sandbox environment bug. I have had exactly the same issue that the

`- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions`

was never called. Only the `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` arrived after the call to `restoreCompletedTransactions`.

I have checked it with an Apple engineer. He confirmed that my code is indeed correct and I should receive the `updatedTransactions` call. He said that the fact this is not happening in the sandbox environment is apparently a bug (he was not surprised about it at all).

Honestly there is not much you can do about it. After he confirmed my code is correct I  took the risk and released the App. It all works as expected with the real iTunes Connect server.

So your best (maybe only) bet is to make sure you have it all set up as expected and go ahead and test it against the live server. Good luck! It worked for me.